# Gas dryer leaking gas only when it runs

Tags: gas, dryer, leaking

I have a samsung gas dryer which appears to leak gas only when it runs. We smell gas in the vent and also, sometimes, near the dryer as well. But more so from the vent, where it's passing raw gas.

And then, we got a repairman come over who charged a bomb to replace the coils, but the leaking continues. When we called him back again, he said that it's the gas valve that's gone wrong. I am not confident that it could be the gas valve. If so, why would it only leak gas when it's running? I'd imagine an improper gas valve not emitting gas, but here, it does emit gas. I am a bit puzzled why the dryer would leak gas only when it runs?
Can it be the igniter or anything else?

Comment: Is he referring to the valve that connects the gas supply to the back of the dryer, or the valve inside the dryer that releases gas to the burner? If it's an internal valve, then it would make sense that it's leaking on the outlet side and thus you're only smelling gas when it's running. Also, I'd _strongly_ recommend that you **don't use the dryer until this is repaired**! As it stands, you're emitting a cloud of natural gas near an open flame. This is a combo that tends to lead to large booms that can destroy houses and kill people.

Comment: You can put soapy water on the valve and connections.  If there is a leak, you will see bubbles.

Comment: What "coils" are you talking about? I agree with @Freeman, that the repairman must have meant the internal dryer gas-control valve. Also, why did the "repairman" NOT repair the appliance?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you got a real winner! I would never call him back ever!
The gas smell can be caused from several things, one common one in appliances in a garage is spiders getting in the vents where the air is mixed not enough air mixture causes incomplete burning and in some cases blocks the gas from getting to the burner.
Another problem is lint getting sucked into the mixing area of the burner and the same issues with spiders. After the gas valve the gas flow is quite small and open to the air or no pressure, the gas blowing by the vents draw air in and to the burner assembly as it exits the burner it is ignited by the pilot or has that is already lit. So I would look for blockages that is allowing gas to exit before it should, other things that could cause this a dirty burner assembly, or crack in the pipe after the gas valve or burner assembly.
I would want to identify the leak or reason there is unburned gas before something gets worse and causes a flash explosion.

Comment: It could also be that the leak IS constant, but gas is heavier than air so it sinks to low spots and you may not smell it until it gets mixed with the surrounding air. Your dryer running is what allows that to happen. The soapy water trick will tell you if it's the valve feeding gas to the dryer, so if it's not there, it's something INSIDE of the dryer and that repair man should have fixed it.

Comment: @JRaef, natural gas is lighter than air. If this is an LPG appliance then yes, heavier than air...